# using the routeprovider to get page part from full page instead off partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to create a website using AngularJS. It's possible to load the partials with the route provider using this code:

```js
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        //route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'Wonen.htm',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/homepage.htm', {
            templateUrl : 'Wonen.htm',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            // redirectTo : redirect
        });
});
```

The page `Wonen.htm` is a partial without header and footer etc. We want to use a complete page, and load the html part we need based on an id from this page.

Is this possible?

Comment: would need to use a `$httpInterceptor` to parse out whatever html you need. Why do you want the full page?

Comment: If we can use the full page it's not necessary to change the CMS, and the page refresh (F5) will automatically working.

Comment: page refresh issue makes no sense. You don't duplicate server routes in angular routes. No point using angular if that's what you are wanting

Comment: At the moment when I refresh a page, I only get the partial, and it's not loading in the template itself.

When we can load a full page and grab an HTML chunk from it, the page refresh is working and we don't need to change every page in the CMS.

Comment: sounds like you have conflicting server/angular routes. Also you aren't using html5Mode so your angular url's should have a `#` in them and refresh would always point to the angular app entry point as far as server is concerned

Comment: I suggest you create a separate development directory for angular while you get the bugs worked out and a better understanding of it's routing. Page refresh should load angular again. You can parse the cms html, but realistically all you need is the content from the cms as json if you are trying to replicate cms in angular

Comment: I know that we only need the content, but that's a separate/internal issue. For now I have to deal with the CMS html, and have to get the content from there.

Comment: You mentioned the $httpInterceptor before, how should I implement this to get it working?

Comment: would need array of template names probably in interceptor, or some identifier in url of template ...then if url matches , create document from the html response and traverse it to return the html wanted. jQuery would be helpful for this

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this:

```js
myApp.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            console.log("On success:", response);
            // do something on success
           
            if() {
                

                return $q.reject(response);
            }

            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            console.log("On error", response);
            // do something on error
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
```

The only I have to do know is edit the response.